New-MgSiteList = "Unable to determine type of provided column definition"
This command does not work as documented. Just following the simple example on the cmdlet help page fails with "Unable to determine type of provided column definition".
Wondering if anyone knows a trick to get around this.  My actual params look like this:
$Params = @{
    displayName = 'EXO Mailbox Size Report'
    columns     = @(
        @{
            name     = 'DisplayName'
            text     = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'PrimarySmtpAddress'
            text     = @{}
            required = $true
            indexed  = $true
        }
        @{
            name         = 'PrimaryQuotaStatus'
            choice       = @{
                allowTextEntry = $false
                choices        = @('OK', 'Issue Warning', 'Prohibit Send', 'Prohibit Send and Receive', 'Unchecked')
                displayAs      = 'dropDownMenu'
            }
            required     = $true
            defaultValue = 'Unchecked'
        }
        @{
            name   = 'MailboxSizeGB'
            number = @{}
        }
        @{
            name     = 'IssueWarningQuota'
            number   = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'ProhibitSendQuota'
            number   = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'ProhibitSendReceiveQuota'
            number   = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name         = 'ArchiveQuotaStatus'
            choice       = @{
                allowTextEntry = $false
                choices        = @('OK', 'Issue Warning', 'Prohibit Send', 'Prohibit Send and Receive', 'Unchecked')
                displayAs      = 'dropDownMenu'
            }
            required     = $true
            defaultValue = 'Unchecked'
        }
        @{
            name   = 'ArchiveSizeGB'
            number = @{}
        }
        @{
            name     = 'ArchiveWarningQuota'
            number   = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'ArchiveQuota'
            number   = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'RecipientTypeDetails'
            text     = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'RetentionPolicy'
            text     = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name     = 'ExoGuid'
            text     = @{}
            required = $true
            indexed  = $true
        }
        @{
            name    = 'EntraObjectId'
            text    = @{}
            indexed = $true
        }
        @{
            name = 'ADDomain'
            text = @{}
        }
        @{
            name = 'ADObjectGuid'
            text = @{}
        }
        @{
            name          = 'ExchangeGuid'
            text          = @{}
            enforceunique = $true
            required      = $true
            indexed       = $true

        }
        @{
            name     = 'ArchiveGuid'
            text     = @{}
            required = $true
        }
        @{
            name        = 'RecoverableItemsGB'
            number      = @{}
            description = 'TotalDeletedItemSize (in gigabytes) from Get-MailboxStatistics.'
        }
        @{
            name        = 'ArchiveRecoverableItemsGB'
            number      = @{}
            description = 'TotalDeletedItemSize (in gigabytes) from Get-MailboxStatistics -Archive.'
        }
        @{
            name     = 'WhenCreated'
            dateTime = @{
                displayAs = 'standard'
                format    = 'dateOnly'
            }
        }
        @{
            name     = 'WhenChanged'
            dateTime = @{
                displayAs = 'standard'
                format    = 'dateOnly'
            }
        }
        @{
            name     = 'WhenMailboxCreated'
            dateTime = @{
                displayAs = 'standard'
                format    = 'dateTime'
            }
        }
        @{
            name     = 'LastUserActionTime'
            dateTime = @{
                displayAs = 'standard'
                format    = 'dateOnly'
            }
        }
    )
    list        = @{
        template = "genericList"
    }
}

New-MgSiteList -SiteId $SiteId -BodyParameter $Params

I tried the exact example from the documentation, as well as my own params with actual columns I want, and in either case I expected a 201 Created response code and a list object in the response body - per the documentation.
I'm unable to find a single online resource where somebody has pulled this off using the official New-MgSiteList cmdlet.  I did find one example where somebody just creates the list with no columns initially.  I'm not looking to do that.

Are you using HTTP 1.0 (stream mode) or HTTP 1.1 Chunk mode.  The example is using Chunk mode and getting status 201.  With HTTP 1.0 you will only get a status of 200 OK.  The error has nothing to do with HTTP 1.0 or HTTP 1.1.  The error has to do with the $Param.  I would start with only a few parameters and slowly add parameters until you find what is causing the error "Unable to determine type of provided column definition"

I have started with the very most basic example that is the exact example from the cmdlet help page, which has 2 columns in it.  So I can't go any more basic unfortunately.  But also, I'm not finding anything related to Chunk vs Stream mode.  Is this something that is controllable when using the Graph PowerShell SDK cmdlets?

It looks like PS with Graph is automatically using http 1.1 and returning status 201 (not 200).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1  The client and server have to be compatible.  The parameters you are using will only work if the server is configured to accept the parameters in the request.  The server is not expecting some of the columns you are sending in the request.  How did you configure the server?  What columns did you configure in your server? You are only showing the client.

Hi, it's SharePoint online and there are no columns yet, as I'm trying to create a new list with all new columns. I feel like the two things (my computer/Microsoft.Graph.Sites module, and SPO) are compatible.  I need to check if this issue exists when I just use Graph directly without the module.
